# Cordova play YouTube video in background

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, youtube, avplayer

I know how to play YouTube videos in iOS  Cordova, but when the app enters the background the video stops and I have to manually resume it.

How can I set the proper background mode so that it keeps playing once the app enters the background?

I have already done a lot of research and tried to implement many solution here from Stack Overflow related to this topic, but none did work for me. On their Q&A site, Apple posted this code:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = <#Get your player item#>;

NSArray *tracks = [playerItem tracks];
for (AVPlayerItemTrack *playerItemTrack in tracks)
{
    // find video tracks
    if ([playerItemTrack.assetTrack hasMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicVisual])
    {
        playerItemTrack.enabled = NO; // disable the track
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know how I could reference to the AVPlayer instance from a UIWebView, but that could be an approach.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Would be useful to know how you are currently playing videos, but have you tried using this plugin:

https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer

NB. after following the install instructions, I had to manually copy the native plugin files into the iOS plugins folder to get it to work.  An example project is included in the source.